# Magento 1.9 Catalog Search result redirect the live website

Tags: magento-1.9, database, catalogsearch, advanced-search

I am trying to find where I did mistake when I search abc in catalog search tab. the link **local.xyz.com/abc.html** Redirect to www.xyz.com/abc.html.
Don't know where I did mistake, I already changed the url rewrite manage ment and reindex in and remove cache but same issue occur.

Comment: which search you are talking about ? you mean product search at front top

Comment: catalog search  for find the product @ShashankKumrawat

Comment: check once your  `Base URL` and `Base Secure URL`  for each store and website scope.

Comment: search URL is generated via  function `getResultUrl` in file `vendor/magento/module-search/Helper/Data.php`  and this function outputs `Base URL`   also try to run command `rm -rf generated/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/*` and then check

Comment: Hi Shashank,
Result Url same as base url and with search term but the issue to redirect on another page. I think some thing I did mistake can we give any hardcoded word from admin panel.

Comment: is anything done with .htacess or url rewrite in admin ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update .
Nothing, I did in .htacess file @ShashankKumrawat.
I found that We are giving hard coded url for a particular term On admin-> catalog-> search term.
Thanks for help.

Comment: ok @AnkushDeora, if you have resolved the error the please write it as answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: Yes, @ShashankKumrawat, I had done. Happy Coding:)-
And once again thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Easest Way to get the particular word, we redirect that term from the admin setting.

IN

Admin-> Catalog -> Search Term.

From there we can change for a particular word to redirect the page, where we want.